# ビューに変数を渡したときのエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ビューに変数を渡したときエラーが出ました。

```
#<Note::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb1cd401e70>
```

と出ました。

自分ではちゃんと定義していると思うので、どこが間違っているのかわかりません。

該当部分のファイルは
top.html.erb には

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kotoritter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.scss">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- <div>タグを追加し、「header」というクラスをつけてください -->
  <div class="header"></div>
  <!-- <div>タグを追加し、「main」というクラスをつけてください -->
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="contents1">
  <%= @notes %> ←ここの部分
  </div>
  <% else %>
  <div class="contents2">
  <h1>ようこそKotoritterへ</h1>
  <p>友だちや魅力的な人々とつながって、興味のある<br>最新情報を見つけましょう。そして、いま起きて<br>いるできごとを様々な角度から見てみましょう。</p>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

home_controller.rbには

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def top
    if user_signed_in?
      # 変数@noteにNoteクラスのインスタンスを代入してください
      @note = Note.new
      # 変数@notesにNoteクラスのインスタンスの配列を降順で代入してください
      @notes = Note.all.order(created_at: :desc)
    else
      @message = "ようこそKotoritterへ！"
    end
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

と記述しました。

Answer (score 0):

`<%= @notes %>`は`<%= render @notes %>`の間違いではないですか？

そもそも`#<Note::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb1cd401e70>`はエラーなのですか？
オブジェクトの内容が出力されているだけでエラーには見えませんが・・・
エラーであればエラー詳細も掲載してください。

Answer (score 0):

最近 Rails やっていないので自信がないですが
@notes は、配列みたいに中に複数の情報が入っているんじゃないでしょうか?
なので、`@notes.each` みたいにして、
中身を1つずつ表示させるとかが必用な気がします。

確かもっと、簡単にやる方法はあった気がするんですが
忘れました。